# Type casting value from UserDefault throws error

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I am trying to fetch a data from `UserDefault` but when I am doing this I am getting error

```
var sharedPreference: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "user-key-value")!
func getLastLoginClientId() -> Int64? {

        for (key, value) in sharedPreference.dictionaryRepresentation() {
            if key == LAST_USER {
                return value as! Int64
            }
        }
        return nil
}
```

I am getting that my key is having some value but when returning it, it throws error.

This is how I save

```
func setLastLoginClientId(clientId: Int64) {
        sharedPreference.set(clientId, forKey: LAST_USER)
        sharedPreference.synchronize()
    }
```

Comment: what is the error ...

Comment: signal SIGABRT is the error

Comment: can you show us how do you save the value

Comment: SIGABRT is the UI error check once

Comment: Why are you manually searching for key in `.dictionaryRepresentation`? `UserDefaults` has own key lookup methods. Like [`integer(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1407405-integer). Just use it.

Comment: @A.Munzer I updated it. pls check

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik no as such descriptive error I could see here

Comment: @user28434 because that was also not working

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala, not working how?

Comment: its returning nil to me. I used this earlier but I found even the data is there and it is returning me nil

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do something as simple as

```
func getLastLoginClientId() -> Int64? {
    return sharedPreference.value(forKey: LAST_USER) as? Int64
}
```

Here is what I've tested

```
struct CustomUserDefaults {

    var sharedPreference    : UserDefaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "user-key-value")!
    let LAST_USER = "test"

    func test() {

        let value = Int64(20.0)
        self.setLastLoginClientId(value)

        let testValue = getLastLoginClientId()
        print(testValue) // 20.0
    }

    func setLastLoginClientId(_ value: Int64) {
        sharedPreference.set(value, forKey: LAST_USER)
    }

    func getLastLoginClientId() -> Int64? {
        return sharedPreference.value(forKey: LAST_USER) as? Int64
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not working. It is returning nil thats why I changed it to that way

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit what is not working? I've updated with a code I tried that is working fine.

Comment: That's 100% correct and it should work like this only but Here it is not happening. It is always returning nil to me in this case only. All other of these kind is returning correct value

Comment: Can you check with a breakpoint you are not resetting the value in UserDefaults before accessing it? Although, is it executed in different thread? Maybe you try to access it before being fully set.

Comment: The variable is reflecting value in debugging and data is already in UserDefaults

Comment: I would suggest to eventually delete your app, clean your project and rerun this example. in case you have corrupted data in UserDefault after trying many times. Otherwise it's something else in your code since this one above is working fine.

Comment: `synchronize()` does not need to be called anymore. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) "Waits for any pending asynchronous updates to the defaults database and returns; **this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used.**"

Comment: @Ben it is working now. I passed it as string for now and typecasted it. Thanx for help. Will b looking in it little later